# How to load a picture using JFileChooser to an existing white background

Tags: java

I have created a little paint like program, and I am wondering if i could load a picture (.jpg .png) to my 'white worksheet' and draw on that. Here is my source code :

```
public class rajzlap extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics2D g2;
private int x = -1, y = -1;

private JFileChooser fileChooser;

private int toolbaritem = -5;
private int vastagsag = 1;


public rajzlap() {
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    image = new BufferedImage(3000, 2000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, 3000, 2000);

    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("kepek (*.jpg)", "jpg"));
    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

}

// load from file
public void loadText() {
    if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileChooser.getSelectedFile())) {

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Nem sikerult beolvasni a szoveget!", "Hiba",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
        if (toolbaritem == 0) {
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(vastagsag));
            if (x != -1 && y != -1) {
                g2.drawLine(x, y, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            repaint();
        } else if (toolbaritem == 1) {
            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(vastagsag));
            if (x != -1 && y != -1) {
                g2.drawLine(x, y, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            repaint();
        } else if (toolbaritem == 2) {
            g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(vastagsag));
            if (x != -1 && y != -1) {
                g2.drawLine(x, y, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            repaint();
        } else if (toolbaritem == 3) {
            g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(vastagsag));
            if (x != -1 && y != -1) {
                g2.drawLine(x, y, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            repaint();
        } else if (toolbaritem == 4) {
            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(vastagsag*2));
            if (x != -1 && y != -1) {
                g2.drawLine(x, y, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    x = -1;
    y = -1;

}

public void pencil() {

    toolbaritem = 0;
    System.out.println(toolbaritem);

}

public void piros() {

    toolbaritem = 1;
    System.out.println(toolbaritem);

}

public void zold() {
    toolbaritem = 2;
    System.out.println(toolbaritem);
}

public void kek() {
    toolbaritem = 3;
    System.out.println(toolbaritem);
}

public void radir() {

    toolbaritem = 4;
    System.out.println(toolbaritem);

}

public void vekony() {

    vastagsag = 1;
    System.out.println(vastagsag);

}

public void kozepes() {

    vastagsag = 5;
    System.out.println(vastagsag);

}

public void vastag() {

    vastagsag = 10;
    System.out.println(vastagsag);

}
```

Here is a picture of my program for better understanding:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWjU9.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you fill your image with a white background you can paint an image on top of the background.

So first get the code working by hard coding the file name of the image you want to load. Once this works then you can get the file name from the JFileChooser.

The basic code would be:

```
g2.fillRect(0, 0, 3000, 2000);
File filename = new File("someFle.jpg");
BufferedImage fileImage = ImageIO.read( filename );
g2.drawImage(fileImage, 0, 0, null);
```

You may want to change the x/y offsets to center the image on the white background.

Comment: from these 3 rows of code that you provided I was able to solve my problem, thank you for that :)